# Creating Relational database with user model in Django. I think i have created relational database but i don't know whats going wrong

Tags: python, django, relational-database

I think i have successfully created relation between user model and another table called shop_details but the data is not been inserted. i don't know what is going wrong.
the code is here.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Shop_Details(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shop_street = models.TextField()
    shop_area = models.TextField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pin_code = models.TextField()
```

my views.py is here

views.py

```
def shop_detils(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        shop_name = request.POST['shop_name']
        shop_street = request.POST['shop_street']
        shop_area = request.POST['shop_area']
        city = request.POST['city']
        state = request.POST['state']
        pin_code = request.POST['pin_code']

        if(len(str(pin_code))!=6):
            messages.info(request,"please provide a valid address pin-code")
            print("niceee...........................")
            return render(request,'shop_details.html')
        else:
            if(is_number(int(pin_code))):
                shop = Shop_Details(shop_name=shop_name,shop_street=shop_street,shop_area=shop_area,city=city,state=state,pin_code=pin_code,user=request.user)
            shop.save()
            
                messages.info(request,"Shop Details Updated")
                shop_data = Shop_Details.objects.filter(user = request.user)
                print(shop_data[1])
                print("congrats...........................")
                return redirect('home',{'data':shop_data})
            else:
                messages.info(request,"please provide a valid address")
                print("nice2222222222222222222222222")
                return render(request,'shop_details.html')

    else:
        return render(request,'shop_details.html')
```

my shop_details.html is here

shop_detsils.html

```
enter code here


{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% csrf_token %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% csrf_token %}
{% load static %}
{% csrf_token %}

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

{% csrf_token %}
<body align="center">
{% csrf_token %}
{% csrf_token %}


    {% csrf_token %}
    
    {% block content %}
    <form action="shop_detils" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
    
    
            

        <div align="center" class='resp_code frms'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p align='center'<h5><font style='font: 1em/1.3em Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;'>
            <b>Shop Details</b></font></h5></p>
            <div id="selection">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <table>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <tr><td>Shop Name: </td><td><input required style="width:200%;" name="shop_name" type="text"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Shop Street: </td><td><input required style="width:200%;" name="shop_street" type="text"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Shop Area: </td><td><input required style="width:200%;" name="shop_area" type="text"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>City: </td><td><input required style="width:200%;" name="city" type="text"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>State: </td><td><input required style="width:200%" list="state" name="state" type="text"></td></tr>
                    <datalist id="state">  
                        <option value="Andhra Pradesh">Andhra Pradesh</option>
                        <option value="Andaman and Nicobar Islands">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
                        <option value="Arunachal Pradesh">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
                        <option value="Assam">Assam</option>
                        <option value="Bihar">Bihar</option>
                        <option value="Chandigarh">Chandigarh</option>
                        <option value="Chhattisgarh">Chhattisgarh</option>
                        <option value="Dadar and Nagar Haveli">Dadar and Nagar Haveli</option>
                        <option value="Daman and Diu">Daman and Diu</option>
                        <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                        <option value="Lakshadweep">Lakshadweep</option>
                        <option value="Puducherry">Puducherry</option>
                        <option value="Goa">Goa</option>
                        <option value="Gujarat">Gujarat</option>
                        <option value="Haryana">Haryana</option>
                        <option value="Himachal Pradesh">Himachal Pradesh</option>
                        <option value="Jammu and Kashmir">Jammu and Kashmir</option>
                        <option value="Jharkhand">Jharkhand</option>
                        <option value="Karnataka">Karnataka</option>
                        <option value="Kerala">Kerala</option>
                        <option value="Madhya Pradesh">Madhya Pradesh</option>
                        <option value="Maharashtra">Maharashtra</option>
                        <option value="Manipur">Manipur</option>
                        <option value="Meghalaya">Meghalaya</option>
                        <option value="Mizoram">Mizoram</option>
                        <option value="Nagaland">Nagaland</option>
                        <option value="Odisha">Odisha</option>
                        <option value="Punjab">Punjab</option>
                        <option value="Rajasthan">Rajasthan</option>
                        <option value="Sikkim">Sikkim</option>
                        <option value="Tamil Nadu">Tamil Nadu</option>
                        <option value="Telangana">Telangana</option>
                        <option value="Tripura">Tripura</option>
                        <option value="Uttar Pradesh">Uttar Pradesh</option>
                        <option value="Uttarakhand">Uttarakhand</option>
                        <option value="West Bengal">West Bengal</option>
                    </datalist>
                    <tr><td>Pin-code: </td><td><input required name="pin_code" type="text"></td></tr>

                </table>
                <input style="border-radius: 0.5em; background-color:rgba(2, 2, 253, 0.753); 
               width:2.5cm;height:0.8cm; font-family: sans-serif;" type="submit" value="Submit">

            </div>
        </div>

            
    </form>
    
    {% endblock %}

</body>
{% endif %}
```

my  layout.html is here. basically Iam extending layout.html in all html files.

layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
{% csrf_token %}
<html>
<title>GrocSale</title>

<head>
   <script language="Javascript" href="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" href="{% static 'js/state.js'%}"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css'%}">
</head>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

{% csrf_token %}
<style>

      * {box-sizing: border-box}



      body{
        background:url("{% static 'groc.jpeg' %}") no-repeat;
        background-size:cover ;
        background-attachment:fixed;
      }
      body:after {
        content: "";
        position: fixed;
        top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; 
        background: hsla(180,0%,50%,0.25);
        pointer-events: none;
      }

      .tab {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        width: 20%;
        height: 1000px;
        
      }

      /* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
      .tab button {
        display: block;
        background-color: inherit;
        color: black;
        padding: 22px 16px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        text-align: left;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }




      /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
      .tab button:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
      }

      /* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
      .tab button.active {
        background-color: #ccc;
      }

      /* Style the tab content */
      .tabcontent {
        float: left;
        padding: 0px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 70%;
        border-left: none;
        height: 300px;
      }

      .divs{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid green;
        padding: 50px;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 1em;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        
        
      }

      .divs:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: gold;
        cursor: grab;
      }

    </style>

   <body>

      {% csrf_token %}

      <header align="center" style="height: 150px;background-color:orange">
      {% csrf_token %}

    <strong>

      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for detail in  data%}
  
      <h1>{{detail.shop_name}}</h1>
      <h4>Arokya,Hatsun,Arun All Products Available Here</h4>
      <h6>{{detail.shop_street}}{{detail.shop_area}}, {{detail.city}}, {{detail.state}} - {{detail.pin_code}}</h6>
  {% endfor %}
    </strong>


  </header>

  <div style="background-color:orange;" class="tab" >
    {% csrf_token %}

  
  <a href="{% url 'home' %}"> <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" >Home</button></a>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" >Add/Update Product</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" >Add Stock/Update Stock</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" >Add Sale</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" >Total Sale</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" >Daily Collection Customers</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" >Today's Collection Status</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" >Show Products</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" >All Stock Orders</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" >Settings</button>
  <a href="{% url 'shop_detils' %}" ><button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" >Shop Details</button></a>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" >Contact Us</button>
  <a href="{% url 'logout' %}"><button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" >Logout</button></a>

  </div>


 

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Iam still a learner in Django.
Thanks in advance.

my error is shown in image
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23gsl.png)

Comment: Your function `shop_detils` is not correctly indented in the above code block

Comment: it iss wrong here but not in my program